# std::cout and printf array

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout, format-specifiers

```
    int arrSize = 10;
    double* arr = new double [arrSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){       
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
        //std::cout<<arr[i];
    }
```

Here

- `printf()` prints 0000000000.
- `cout` prints 0123456789.

Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a wrong format specifier for any particular argument in `printf()` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`arr` is a `double` array, hence `arr[i]` produces a `double` type value. you need `%f` format specifier to print that. If you use `%d` to print a `double`, your program faces UB and the result cannot be justified, in can be *anything*.

OTOH, the `<<` used with `cout` is an overloaded operator which can *adapt* based on the type of the supplied variable. So, it prints the output as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`arr[i]` is a `double`, but `%d` is the format specifier for `int`. It is undefined behavior to use the wrong format specifier. From the C11 standard, 7.21.6.1/9:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

There are lots of format specifiers for `double` that will format the output in different ways, see [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for a full list.

On the other hand, [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for `cout` has an overload that takes a `double` directly (#5 in the linked reference), so that just works.